# run Spring 3 application on Glassfish 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, glassfish

I try to run my Spring MVC application (that works nice on tomcat 7.0.41) on Glassfish 4 and something goes wrong.
I'm very newbie on Glassfish, so I simply use IntelliJ IDEA run configuration for start it.
But when I try to run I have this stacktrace in Glassfish log:

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in class path resource [data-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'validationMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/validator/resourceloading/ResourceBundleLocator;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5898)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'validationMessageSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/validator/resourceloading/ResourceBundleLocator;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    ... 60 more]]
```

data-context.xml (in which prpbably some ambiguity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mvc"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="1234"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mvc.logic.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basenames="classpath:META-INF/i18n/application, classpath:META-INF/i18n/formats, classpath:META-INF/i18n/validation_messages"
        />

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc.logic" />
```

It connect to application context that way:

web.xml

```
    ...
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:root-context.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
    ...
```

root-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
        <import resource="data-context.xml"/>
        <import resource="security-context.xml"/>
    </beans>
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the class loading of Hibernate Validator library - it's likely that you have another version of this library installed on your Glassfish, I'm not acquainted with Glassfish but it's likely an older version of the validator jar is bundled with it.

Comment: agree that the problem is with validator, but more likely it is newer, as Glassfish 4 is implementation for Java EE 7. I would try your application with Glassfish 3.

Comment: Where are you libraries come from? Do you use maven and they are freezed, or do you depend on container's provided jars?

Comment: @Boris Treunkov, yep this is some sort of dependency conflict between GF and my build in libraries. Thanks, it was halpful enough. If you formalize this as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @madhead I use maven without any Glassfish plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the class loading of Hibernate Validator library - it's likely that you have another version of this library installed on your Glassfish.

You can read more about classloading order in Glassfish 4.0 at [GlassFish Server Development Guide  4.0](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/application-development-guide.pdf)  there is a whole *Chapter 2 - Classloaders*.